# Image doesn't visible in google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, google-colaboratory

from IPython.display import Image
Image("drive/My Drive/dog-breed/train/001513dfcb2ffafc82cccf4d8bbaba97")

when I run the code above in the google colab, the image doesn't visible and I got the output as below,

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CqU7n.png)

Anyone please let me know how to sort this out

Comment: Make sure you have mounted your drive to google colab like [this tutorial](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=RWSJpsyKqHjH), and check the path of image by `os.path.exists()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mention the image file type along with the image address parse

Example:

```
from IPython.display import Image 
Image("/content/test.jpg")
```